# Apache Camel - call simple language without side effect

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to call an object with the `Simple` language directly within the route and without side effects? The 2 approaches i've tried are;

```
.toD("${header.exchangeHelper.inc1()}") //works but fails if there is a return type from the called method
.bean(new Simple("${header.exchangeHelper.inc1()}")) //works but sets the body to false
```

Neither of which give the ideal solution.

Comment: You can pass `InOnly` as parameter of `toD`. pattern is an enum with three values InOnly, InOut, InOptionalOut Check out https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/toD-eip.html

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result to exchange property or header instead. This way you'll keep the original body and get the result from your method in case you need it later. Alternatively you can just call the method using a processor.

These are generally better approaches with Java-DSL for something like this than using simple-language since they benefit from IDE's refactoring tools, error highlighting and many forms of linting.

```java
package com.example;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    ExchangeHelper exchangeHelper = mock(ExchangeHelper.class);

    @Test
    public void useSetPropertyTest() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        resultMockEndpoint.message(0).body().isEqualTo("Hello");

        when(exchangeHelper.inc1()).thenReturn(true);

        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:useSetProperty", "Hello", 
            "exchangeHelper", exchangeHelper);

        verify(exchangeHelper, times(1)).inc1();
        resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Test
    public void justUseProcessorTest() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        resultMockEndpoint.message(0).body().isEqualTo("Hello");

        when(exchangeHelper.inc1()).thenReturn(true);

        template.sendBody("direct:justUseProcessor", "Hello");

        verify(exchangeHelper, times(1)).inc1();
        resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Test
    public void useHeaderFromProcessorTest() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        resultMockEndpoint.message(0).body().isEqualTo("Hello");

        when(exchangeHelper.inc1()).thenReturn(true);

        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:useHeaderFromProcessor", "Hello", 
            "exchangeHelper", exchangeHelper);

        verify(exchangeHelper, times(1)).inc1();
        resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {

        return new RouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
             
                from("direct:useSetProperty")
                    .setProperty("result")
                        .simple("${header.exchangeHelper.inc1()}")
                    .log("Body: ${body} Result header: ${exchangeProperty.result}")
                    .to("mock:result")
                    .removeProperty("result");

                from("direct:justUseProcessor")
                    .process( ex -> { exchangeHelper.inc1(); })
                    .log("Body: ${body}")
                    .to("mock:result");

                from("direct:useHeaderFromProcessor")
                    .process( ex -> {  
                        ex.getMessage()
                            .getHeader("exchangeHelper", ExchangeHelper.class)
                            .inc1();
                    })
                    .log("Body: ${body}")
                    .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }

    interface ExchangeHelper {
        public boolean inc1();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i'm not looking to create any additional headers or exchangeProperties but to invoke calls on existing header/property objects..

Comment: Added `direct:justUseProcessor` and `"direct:useHeaderFromProcessor` to the example. First one allows you to call method of an object without even having to register it as header to your route, second calls the method using header. I personally would avoid using simple language for something like this outside of templating (i.e velocity or thymeleaf) or YAML/XML-DSL  to get the benefits provided by linting/error highlighting, intellisense/code completion and type-safety.

Comment: Excellent point about intellisense/hightlighting/linting..

Answer (score 0):

Not tried, but why not using the **wiretap** EIP to issue an extra (and separated!) request to your requestHelper method ?

Something like:

```
from("direct:demo")
    .wireTap("bean:${header.exchangeHelper.inc1()}")
    .to("direct:doSomething");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Camel Script, something like that:

```
from("direct:exampleScript")
    .script().simple("${header.exchangeHelper.inc1()}")
    .log("End")
;
```